# Problem with Expo Authentication with Facebook and AuthSession API

Tags: react-native, expo, facebook-authentication

I had my Expo app with SDK 46 and I migrated to SDK 48. I have a Facebook login in my app and it was working perfectly with `expo-facebook` package. With SDK 48 is required to use AuthSession API using expo-auth-session.

I followed all the instructions from here: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/facebook-authentication/ and I double check my Facebook app login settings:

[image]

In the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs field the red numbers from image are:

1. my expo whoami (login) and the second part
2. slug value inside my app.json

Then in my app I setup everything as in the document and then I generate a development build:

```
eas build --profile development --platform ios
```

Then, once installed I ran:

```
expo start --dev-client
```

Just after the app main screen shows I can see the following message:

> You need to add this url to your authorized redirect urls on your Facebook app: fb{here is my fb app id}://authorize

[image]

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1):

you try to update the schema inside of app.json to an array with you actual schema and the schema for Facebook ?

some like this

```
{"expo":"scheme":["myAppSchema","fbYOUR_FB_APP_ID"]}
```